# jQuery colorbox not working in IE8 (But works in IE7?)

Tags: css, wordpress, colorbox, nextgen-gallery

I'm working on a clients website and for some reason the jQuery colorbox plugin isn't working correctly in IE8 on this site, it's opening the colorbox and has no width. The gallery is running NextGEN gallery.

http://bwosoyoos.lexcorp.ca/photo-gallery/

The main reason I don't understand this is because I've got the exact same thing running on another site and it works fine (also using the same theme/css for the colorbox)

If anyone can shine some light onto this I'd be beyond grateful.

Comment: side note: Reservation calendar select dates, thing, cuts off the 2 in 2012 with chrome. Maybe smaller size?

Comment: Fixed that, thanks! Hadn't done a sweep with chrome yet.

Comment: I don't even see where you are using the colorbox plugin. Where's the trigger?

Comment: You just click on any image and it opens the colorbox?

Comment: My bad, I was provided an improper link, I've corrected it: http://bwosoyoos.lexcorp.ca/photo-gallery/

Comment: @BryanDowning It looks like ColorBox is being used in conjunction with other scripts and/or loaders.

Comment: I'm not sure what to do in order to fix this, I've tried switching the script to Lightbox as well and that did nothing.. I've got the exact same gallery/script running on another site and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to figure out a direct cause, and I'd also tried switching to Lightbox Plus instead of jQuery Colorbox.. but it's still the same issue.

I've added a warning message that pops up when people view that page on IE 8 or lower expressing that it won't function correctly and providing a link to update IE, or download another browser via BrowseHappy.com .. that's the best I can do for now. :/